# Gradle custom plugin : add dependency from extension object

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write a plugin which adds dependencies to `project.dependencies` according to informations gathered in the plugin extension object. But it seems to be impossible.

Indeed, the data from extension object is only available in a new task or in `project.afterEvaluate` closure, but dependencies added in those places are ignored.

---

The following code tries to add the dependency in `afterEvaluate` but the dependency is ignored :

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin

myplugin {
  version '1.0'
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.extensions.create('myplugin', MyPluginExtension)

    project.afterEvaluate {
       def version = project.myplugin.version
       project.dependencies.add("compile", "org.foo:bar:$version") // --> ignored
    }
  }
}

class MyPluginExtension {
  def version
}
```

---

In the following code the dependency injection works but I don't have access to the extension object :

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin

myplugin {
  version '1.0'
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.extensions.create('myplugin', MyPluginExtension)    

    def version = project.myplugin.version // == null
    project.dependencies.add("compile", "org.foo:bar:$version") // --> fail because $version is null

  }
}

class MyPluginExtension {
  def version
}
```

Is there a solution ?

Comment: You'll have to defer accessing the extension, in one way or another. It's not clear to me why adding dependencies in `project.afterEvaluate` wouldn't work. Might be a problem with the code that uses the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I simplified the code to stay clear, you can find the whole code [here](https://github.com/tbruyelle/ResetUnreadSms/blob/aa-plugin/build.gradle). It's an android plugin for a library which generates java classes from annotations. The plugin works well without extension objects, but fails if I want to inject dependencies with data from extension objects, as explained in the question.

Comment: cc @PeterNiederwieser in case you haven't been notified by my answer...

Comment: Android changes the game. I'm afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks then I will try on the adt-dev group

Comment: @tbruyelle I'm experiencing same issue. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 19):

**Update**: I managed to figure this out since my original answer. The way do this is to add a `DependencyResolutionListener` in which you add the dependencies and then remove the listener so it doesn't try to add them on later resolution steps.

```
compileDeps = project.getConfigurations().getByName("compile").getDependencies()
project.getGradle().addListener(new DependencyResolutionListener() {
    @Override
    void beforeResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {
        compileDeps.add(project.getDependencies().create("org.foo:bar:$version"))
        project.getGradle().removeListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    void afterResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {}
})
```

I have a working example of a plugin that uses this [here](https://github.com/saadfarooq/gradle-common-deps-plugin)

**Original Answer:**

This is also late but for anyone dropping in. With the latest gradle (`2.6` at the time of writing), you can add a `DependencyResolutionListener` and add any dependencies before dependencies are resolved.

```
project.getGradle().addListener(new DependencyResolutionListener() {
    @Override
    void beforeResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {
        depsToAdd.each { dep ->
            compileConfig.getDependencies()
                .add(project.getDependencies().create(dep))
        }
    }

    @Override
    void afterResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {

    }
})
```

However, as of this writing I was having some issues getting this to work with Android Studio IDE. The problem is tracked in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570756/custom-plugin-adding-dependency-beforeresolve-from-android-studio)

Comment: It does not work in Gradle 5.3.1. I get error: `Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':compile' after it has been resolved.`.

Comment: Could you explains what's the difference between it and `dependencyNotations.forEach(d -> project.getDependencies().add(configuration.getName(), d));` ?

Comment: this resolves into an exception `InvalidUserData: A path must be specified!`

Answer (score 5):

I originally implemented this solution using the `DependencyResolutionListener` approach by Saad. However, the listener itself is called [only when something iterates over the configuration associated with the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22049146/263004). For example, if you want to dynamically add a dependency to `compile`, you have to make sure that something later on does something like:

```
project.configurations.compile.each {
   ...
}
```

But this is something that happens as a matter of course, since `compile` is a known configuration for any project that uses the java plugin. However, if you are using a custom configuration (as I was), then the listener approach won't work unless you explicitly iterate over your custom configuration.

I was able to find a better way to do this, and within `afterEvaluate` as the OP originally wanted. I'm using a custom configuration here, but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work for `compile` either:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    def version = project.myPlugin.version
    project.configurations.myConfig.dependencies.add(
        project.dependencies.add("myConfig", "org.foo:bar:$version")
    )
}
```

Of course, at some point something still has to iterate over the dependencies for them to actually get resolved.

Comment: Thanks this works great - BUT i have a question.

Why is the default `dependency` block not lazy. Gradle is pushing for the lazy API in every corner (which is good) but then one part is not lazy and cumbersome to configure because it adds like ~4 likes per dependency type you want to do dynamic?

Do you have any insight?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this:

```
project.dependencies {
  delegate.compile("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1")
}
```

Comment: what does this look like using a Java API? (instead of groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if that's still relevant, but you can workaround this by explicitly adding your compile configuration to Java classpath in doFirst:

```
variant.javaCompile.doFirst {
    variant.javaCompile.classpath += project.configurations.myconfiguration
}
```