# Gradle: task with a custom dependency configuration?

Tags: gradle

My project has a bunch of modules and while each module applies the java plugin and has normal compile, test, jar, and such steps, the outer project doesn't. However, the outer project does have a task that wraps up a bunch of files, reports, and such and does some processing. This task needs a particular zip file that nothing else needs.

I need that task to resolve and download a dependency, so if I run:

```
gradle doWeeklySummaryTask
```

It'll go fetch the necessary zip, just like compile fetches all the compile dependencies.

I can create a custom dependency, that's easy enough:

```
configurations {
   foo
}
dependencies {
   foo('blah:blah:blah')
}
```

The question is, how do I get my doWeeklySummaryTask to resolve that dependency?

Comment: Doesn't complain, but doesn't resolve it either. Nice idea though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dependency will be automatically resolved as soon as some piece of code iterates over `configurations.foo`.

Comment: Doesn't appear to. I added "configurations.foo.dependencies.each { dep -> println dep.name }" to my custom task and while it prints the name, it doesn't download it (it's not in my .gradle cache).

Comment: The files will be downloaded when you iterate over the files (`configurations.foo.each`).

Comment: Ah, ok, iterating over configurations.foo.dependencies.each doesn't cause the download. Iterating over configurations.foo.each does. Not sure why (I say that a lot with Gradle), but I'll take it!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, but this really needs to be documented somewhere, especially in the documentation for `DependencyResolutionListener`. It's not obvious when dependency resolution happens and what triggers it.