# Custom plugin adding dependency beforeResolve from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a custom Gradle plugin that uses the following code:

```
project.getGradle().addListener(new DependencyResolutionListener() {
    @Override
    void beforeResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {
        depsToAdd.each { dep ->
            compileConfig.getDependencies()
                .add(project.getDependencies()
                .create(dep)
        }

    }

    @Override
    void afterResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {

    }
})
```

This seems to work fine from command line. However, if I refresh gradle from Android Studio, it barfs with `Cannot change configuration :app:compile after it has been resolved`

My guess is there is some sort of caching going on or Studio builds more variants (I just run the assemble for the variant I want from command line which works every time).

Does anyone know what might be going on and how best to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure this out. The way do this is to add a `DependencyResolutionListener` in which you add the dependencies and then remove the listener so it doesn't try to add them on later resolution steps.

```
compileDeps = project.getConfigurations().getByName("compile").getDependencies()
project.getGradle().addListener(new DependencyResolutionListener() {
    @Override
    void beforeResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {
        compileDeps.add(project.getDependencies().create("org.foo:bar:$version"))
        project.getGradle().removeListener(this)
    }

    @Override
    void afterResolve(ResolvableDependencies resolvableDependencies) {}
})
```

I have a working example of a plugin that uses this [here](https://github.com/saadfarooq/gradle-common-deps-plugin)